# Checking for proper xml before parsing in NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I give non-xml string (or junk xml) to NSXMLParser it will result in crash. How validate xml before passing it to NSXMLParser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will not crash, if `NSXMLParser` finds an error, it will let you know through its delegate, either by invoking `parser:validationErrorOccurred:` or `– parser:parseErrorOccurred:`. You can use the `- (NSError  *)parserError` in `NSXMLParser` to determine the error wich caused the parsing to terminate.

I hope it helps you!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks :) you are right.. i was passing NSError pointer as nil. This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having a validating parser in place can reduce the required code to parse XML a lot,
Check the the blog post **IPHONE: LIBXML2 & RELAX NG VALIDATION**

http://blog.mro.name/2010/05/iphone-libxml2-relax-ng-validation/

Comment: Iam not worried about tag name mismatch etc.. i just don't want a crash by NSXMLParser because of providing non-xml data to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement following delegate methods for ParseOperation delegate :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```