# Validate a XML file in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing

I have a XML parser. I'm getting the XML file from server and write that XML file in to a local file in cache. Before do that, I want to check the URL has the XML file. How Can I check the available URL's page is a XML page or another type of page(Ex:HTML,PHP)?? Simply how can I identify a XML file ??

Comment: By the way, splitting hairs, PHP is not a type of response, but rather a server language for generating a response. It's possible for PHP to return XML or HTML (or JSON or an image or ...). I suspect you don't care whether the server is using PHP, but rather just the content type (HTML, XML, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you have to look at the contents of the data retrieved to make sure it's valid XML, and parsing is the easiest way to do that.

If you're retrieving the data via a HTTP request, you can, though, also look at the response you receive before you start receiving the actual data. For example, if using `NSURLConnection`, you can implement a `didReceiveResponse`, which should often return a `200` for status code and `text/xml` for content type:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (id)response;

        NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
        NSString *contentType = httpResponse.allHeaderFields[@"Content-Type"];
        NSLog(@"%d; %@", statusCode, contentType);

        // check to see if statusCode == 200 and/or [contentType isEqualToString:@"text/xml"] here;
    }
}
```

As an aside, the status code and the content type are set by the server, so it is, admittedly, dependent upon the server's implementation (e.g. if the XML is being generated programmatically by the server, hopefully it's setting these HTTP response fields correctly, but if you're retrieving XML from third party servers, you can't be guaranteed that they're well-behaved). But a status code of 200 and content type of "text/xml" are customary and most servers will set these values appropriately if you're just retrieving a XML file.

The most reliable technique for validating your XML is to just receive the data from the server, and submit it to a parser, and see if the parser returns an error or not.

Comment: @RachithaS See [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) or the corresponding [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). For example, you'll get a 404 status code if the URL for your XML was not found (and the data you'll end up receiving is generally an HTML page saying that it wasn't found rather than a well-formed XML).

Comment: @Rob: This is not working. I'm getting this Exception. "erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData statusCode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: @enadun That error suggests that you tried doing `statusCode` with a `NSData` object. If you look at my above code sample (a) I'm doing it in `didReceiveResponse`; and (b) I'm checking to make sure that `response` is a kind of `NSHTTPURLResponse` object. It almost sounds like you're trying to use `statusCode` in `didReceiveData` (which wouldn't possibly work), or something like that. Look at where you use `statusCode` and make sure you're not trying to use that with a `NSData` object. Update your question with code sample if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are various solution available for this:

http://knol2share.blogspot.in/2009/05/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-c.html

http://wiki.njh.eu/XML-Schema_validation_with_libxml2

[Checking for proper xml before parsing in NSXMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800360/checking-for-proper-xml-before-parsing-in-nsxmlparser)

Hope this will help you.